# False eclipse warning underlines in the C/C++ code

Tags: c, eclipse, macos

I am using ACS STM32Workbench on Mac which is based on eclipse IDE. I am getting the following false syntax error warning and my code gets yellow-highlighted which is so irritating. In the Problems tab, there is no information about the warning.

I tried adding braces, cleaning the project, freshen all files in C/C++ Indexer, etc. but no luck. I also do not want to disable this features as its definitely useful, but the false-positives are irritating.
[image: fake warnings]
Please help.

**EDIT**

All the headers are included properly which defines these structs/macros.

```
#define GPIOA_BASE (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0800U)
#define GPIOB_BASE (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0C00U)
#define GPIOC_BASE (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x1000U)
#define GPIOD_BASE (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x1400U)
#define GPIOA ((GPIO_Regdef_t*)GPIOA_BASE);
#define GPIOB ((GPIO_Regdef_t*)GPIOB_BASE);
#define GPIOC ((GPIO_Regdef_t*)GPIOC_BASE);
#define GPIOD ((GPIO_Regdef_t*)GPIOD_BASE);

typedef struct
{
    __IO uint32_t CRLR;
    __IO uint32_t CRHR;
    __IO uint32_t IDR;
    __IO uint32_t ODR;
    __IO uint32_t BSRR;
    __IO uint32_t BRR;
    __IO uint32_t LCKR;
}GPIO_Regdef_t;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a macro definition:

```
#define GPIOA ((GPIO_Regdef_t*)GPIOA_BASE);
```

Here's a use:

```
    if(pGPIOX == GPIOA)
```

So we can replace `GPIOA` with its definition:

```
    if(pGPIOX ==  ((GPIO_Regdef_t*)GPIOA_BASE);)
```

Observe the semicolon from the definition of `GPIOA`.

(I didn't show the substitution of `GPIOA_BASE` since it's not relevant here.)